# Formencode OneOf validator with dynamic list to test against

Tags: python, validation, turbogears2, formencode

I'm using formencode 1.3.0a1 (and turbogeras 2.3.4) and run into a problem with the validator OneOf.

I want to validate some input according to a list in the Database.
Here is my validation schema and the method for getting the list:

```
from formencode import Schema, validators

def getActiveCodes():
    codes = DBSession.query(SomeObject.code).all()
    codes = [str(x[0]) for x in codes]
    return codes

class itemsEditSchema(Schema):
    code = validators.OneOf(getActiveCodes())
    allow_extra_fields = True
```

The method "getActiveCodes" is executed just once (I guess during schema init or something like that).

I need it to run every time when I want to check my user input for "code", how can I do that?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you see my answer below?  If so, is there any further help or information I can provide, so that you can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I worte a FancyValidtor instead of using OneOf, here is my code:

```
class codeCheck(FancyValidator):
    def to_python(self, value, state=None):
        if value==None:
            raise Invalid('missing a value', value, state)
        return super(codeCheck,self).to_python(value,state)

    def _validate_python(self, value, state):
        codes = DBSession.query(Code).all()
        if value not in codes:
            raise Invalid('wrong code',value, state)
        return value


class itemsEditSchema(Schema):
    code = codeCheck ()
    allow_extra_fields = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to make *formencode* do what you ask.  However, since this is Python, there are few limits to what we can do.

You can solve this by wrapping the call to `getActiveCodes` in a purpose-built class.  The wrapper class, `RefreshBeforeContainsCheck`, will implement the special methods `__iter__` and `__contains__` to provide the necessary interface to be *used as* a iterable object:

```
from formencode import Schema, validators, Invalid

class RefreshBeforeContainsCheck(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        self._current_list = None

    def __iter__(self):
        print '__iter__ was called.'
        #return iter(self._func())  # Could have refreshed here too, but ...
        return iter(self._current_list)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        print '__contains__ was called.'
        self._current_list = self._func()  # Refresh list.
        return item in self._current_list
```

I've added print statements to make it clearer how it behaves during run-time.  The `RefreshBeforeContainsCheck` class can then be used like

```
class ItemsEditSchema(Schema):
    code = validators.OneOf(RefreshBeforeContainsCheck(getActiveCodes))
    allow_extra_fields = True
```

in the validator schema.

The way it is implemented above, the `getActiveCodes` function will be called each time the `OneOf` validator performs an `item in list` test (where our class acts as the `list`), because that will cause `RefreshBeforeContainsCheck.__contains__` to be called.  Now, if the validation fails, the `OneOf` validator generates an error message listing all the elements of `list`; that case is handled by our `__iter__` implementation.  To avoid calling the database twice in case of validation errors, I've chosen to cache the "database" result list as `self._current_list`, but whether or not that's appropriate depends on your needs.

I've created a gist for this: https://gist.github.com/mtr/9719d08f1bbace9ebdf6, basically creating an example of using the above code with the following code.

```
def getActiveCodes():
    # This function could have performed a database lookup.
    print 'getActivityCodes() was called.'
    codes = map(str, [1, 2, 3, 4])
    return codes

def validate_input(schema, value):
    print 'Validating: value: {!r}'.format(value)
    try:
        schema.to_python(value)
    except Invalid, error:
        print 'error: {!r}'.format(error)

    print

def main():
    schema = ItemsEditSchema()

    validate_input(schema, {'code': '3'})
    validate_input(schema, {'code': '4'})
    validate_input(schema, {'code': '5'})
```

The output of the gist is:

```
Validating: value: {'code': '3'}
__contains__ was called.
getActivityCodes() was called.

Validating: value: {'code': '4'}
__contains__ was called.
getActivityCodes() was called.

Validating: value: {'code': '5'}
__contains__ was called.
getActivityCodes() was called.
__iter__ was called.
error: Invalid("code: Value must be one of: 1; 2; 3; 4 (not '5')",
   {'code': '5'}, None, None, 
   {'code': Invalid(u"Value must be one of: 1; 2; 3; 4 (not '5')",
       '5', None, None, None)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I ended up writing a FacnyValidator instead of using one of validator